# Laravel one to many relationship issue with credits name

Tags: laravel-5, relationship, one-to-many

I'm defining a simple one to many relationship in laravel. A User has many Credits and a Credit belongs to a User.

User Model

```
/**
 * Relationship to the users credits
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function credits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Credit::class);
}
```

Credit Model

```
/**
 * Relationship to the user that this credit belongs to
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Controller

```
/**
 * Return a user
 *
 * @param $user_id
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser($user_id)
{
    $user = $this->user->findOrFail($user_id);
     // Dumping and Dieing works fine, but when i return 
     // the User instance i get an error.
     // dd($user->toArray()); 
    return $user;
}
```

Error that I am getting:

"error":0,"message":"Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int"

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

There was another place in the model that expected the $this->credits to return null.  That code was anticipating this code update but did not account for the fact that $this->credits would be a collection.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the user from this user_id just write `User::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first()` in your controller.
and don't forget to pass user_id from your blade to controller.
I hope that's work for you